# What's the most effective way to squash a javascript array of linked records?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple list of javascript objects, each with a single start and end property (datetime)

the dates are grouped in increments of 15 minutes so I have a data structure like this

```
01/01/1999 07:00:00 - 07:15:00
01/01/1999 07:15:00 - 07:30:00
01/01/1999 07:30:00 - 07:45:00
01/01/1999 09:00:00 - 09:15:00
//and so on
```

Gaps are possible when a time slot is filled, so in the above you notice that from 7:45 - 9 the array is missing data. I'd like an effecient way to loop through this array and combine any records that are between these gaps.

the desired output for the above input

```
01/01/1999 07:00:00 - 07:45:00
01/01/1999 09:00:00 - 09:15:00
//and so on
```

How should I approach this problem using vanilla javascript?

**Update**

These records are sorted before I perform this squash.

I don't want anything to fill the gaps (just leave them out)

this will never go beyond the 7am - 7pm date ranges (so you can ignore the midnight issue)

Comment: the periods are sorted ?

Comment: you want a code to fill the gap ? like that: 8:00:00 then 8:15:00 etc ...?

Comment: if they sorted, just compare prev end with current start and if they equal set previous end to current end.

Comment: your format btw, do not cover cases when period getting through midnight. better use datetime or unixtime and never worry.

Comment: I updated the question to cover these comments -thanks !

Comment: so you already got the answer, sorry I will not code for you. use `.split()` to get start/end, use `===` to compare  strings. use `for` to loop

Comment: The reason I'm writing is I'd like an efficient approach (is a nested for loop the only approach to solve this)?

Comment: @eicto The comparisons are not the root of how to solve this problem. The iterations and recursive nature of it is the root of its difficulty. Not only that, why would you want to use `split()` to compare when date objects natively support inequality operations???

Comment: @FeistyMango It is not date objects.

Comment: `I have a simple list of javascript objects, each with a single start and end property (datetime)` Sounds like the OP said, he is using date objects.

Comment: Yes, missed this, so split not need. what the problem to compare Datetimes ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/K5HKy/

Comment: @ToranBillups Does the data ever have scenarios where the dates are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFidle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/UULYV/)***

You are going to need to split the date strings apart by " " and then do some logic while looping.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("01/01/1999 07:00:00 - 07:15:00");
arr.push("01/01/1999 07:15:00 - 07:30:00");
arr.push("01/01/1999 07:30:00 - 07:45:00");
arr.push("01/01/1999 09:00:00 - 09:15:00");

function transform(input){
 var output = [];
 var year = input[0].split(" ")[0];
 var firstStart;
 var previousEnd;
 for(var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++){
    var pieces = input[i].split(" ");
    var start = pieces[1];
    var end = pieces[3];
    if( typeof(firstStart) == "undefined" ){
     firstStart = start;
     previousEnd = end;
    }else{
     if( start == previousEnd ){
        previousEnd = end;
     }else{
        output.push(year+" "+firstStart+" - "+previousEnd);
        firstStart = start;
        previousEnd = end;
     }
    }
    if( i == (len-1) ){
        output.push(year+" "+firstStart+" - "+previousEnd);
    }
 }
 console.log(input);
 console.log(output);
 return output;
}

arr = transform(arr);
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks for putting in the time to crank this out!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I'm imagining as your rough structure:

```
Period = function(start, end){ 
  this.start : // some date obj, stored as milliseconds since 01/01/1970
  this.end   : // some later date obj
};

var periods = [new Period(s1, e1), new Period(s2, e2), ..., new Period(sn, en)]; 
periods.sort(someSortingFunction);
```

If your structure is like this, then you can use the filter iterator function like so:

```
var filteredArray = periods.filter(function(period, index, periods) {
    // 900000 ms in 15 min
    return (index === 0) ? true : (period.start - periods[index - 1].end) > 900000;
}
```

Array.filter returns an array of the elements for which the callback function given returns true. So in this case, if two elements are less than or equal to 15 minutes apart, then they are not returned.

I'm new to JS so comments are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
var div = document.getElementById("div1"),
    arr = new Array(
        "01/01/1999 07:00:00 - 07:15:00",
        "01/01/1999 07:15:00 - 07:30:00",
        "01/01/1999 07:30:00 - 07:45:00",
        "01/01/1999 09:00:00 - 09:15:00",
        "01/01/1999 09:15:00 - 09:30:00",
        "01/01/1999 09:30:00 - 09:45:00",
        "01/01/1999 10:15:00 - 10:30:00",
        "01/01/1999 10:30:00 - 10:45:00"
        ),
    i,
    len = arr.length,
    start = arr[0].substr(0, 19);
    for(i = 1; i < len; i++){
        if(arr[i-1].substr(22, 8) != arr[i].substr(11, 8)){
        div.innerHTML += "<p>"+start+" - "+arr[i-1].substr(22, 8)+"</p>";
        start = arr[i].substr(0, 19);
        }
    }
    div.innerHTML += "<p>"+start+" - "+arr[len-1].substr(22, 8)+"</p>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @eicto Thank you very much for pointing out my mistake. Please check this... http://jsbin.com/IfeFENa/5/edit.